# How to put a hidden form inside a table?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to HTML and RoR. I try to have a button in side a table that submits a hidden form. But for some reason the button does not show up in the generated HTML.

```
<table class="centerBox">
  <h3>Search Results:</h3>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Code</th>
    <th>Subject_id</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  <% @searchResults.each do |searchResult| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= searchResult.name %></td>
      <td><%= searchResult.code %></td>
      <td><%= searchResult.subject_id %></td>
      <td>
        <% form_for(:enrollment, url: enroll_path) do |f| %>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.hidden_field(:enrollment, :course_name => searchResult.name)%>
            <%= f.hidden_field(:enrollment, :user_id => current_user) %>
            <%= f.submit "Enroll"%>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Generated HTML:

```
<tr>
      <td>Independent Study</td>
      <td>AAAS 98B</td>
      <td>1161-100</td>
      <td>
      </td>
</tr>
```

On web page:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For erb code to print the output of the methods you call you need to use the = for the <%= %> tags, just like you did for the fields and the submit button.

```
<%= form_for(:enrollment, url: enroll_path) do |f| %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.hidden_field(:enrollment, :course_name => searchResult.name) %>
    <%= f.hidden_field(:enrollment, :user_id => current_user) %>
    <%= f.submit "Enroll"%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```